# zerok/celery-prometheus-exporter gives celery_workers count as 0

Tags: celery, airflow, prometheus, flower, exporter

I could see flower is showing worker count as 1, But in exporter metrics, i see a worker count as zero.
i am following the below url

https://github.com/zerok/celery-prometheus-exporter

here is my docker-compose and prometheus.yml file:

```
docker-compoe.yml
.... 
celery-exporter:
    image: zerok/celery-prometheus-exporter
    ports:
        - '8888:8888'
```

and my prometheus.yml

```
prometheus.yml
.....
  - job_name: celery-exporter
  static_configs:
    - targets: ['celery-exporter:8888']
```

Let me know if i have to configure anything in **airflow.cfg** file to enable it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you update the question with the entire contents of your docker-compose file?

Answer (score 0):

By default celery-prometheus-exporter connect to redis://redis:6379/**0**.
But my airflow-instance use database named "1", not "0", so I use env

> BROKER_URL=redis://redis:password@172.17.0.1:6379/**1**

172.17.0.1 - is default docker0 ip-address.

Chech name of you redis database.